# Inout parameters in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

This is my code:

```
func removeFromString( _ s: inout String, Character c:Character) -> Int {
    var s1 = s
    var nRemoved = 0

    while let ix = s1.characters.index(of: c) {
        s1.removeSubrange(ix...ix)
        nRemoved += 1

    }
    return nRemoved
}

var s2 = "everest"

let resb = removeFromString(&s2, Character: Character("e"))
```

My problem is this is supposed to change s2 to **"vrst"** after using the `inout` parameter `s`. But it's not modifying the `var s2` at all. What wrong I'm I doing? Or I'm expecting a wrong output? Do help. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By moving `s` into `s1` you are making a copy of it since String is a struct, and all structs are pass by value. So in the end you're only changing `s1` and not the passed in string, `s`. Just remove it:

```
func removeFromString( _ s: inout String, Character c:Character) -> Int {
    var nRemoved = 0

    while let ix = s.characters.index(of: c) {
        s.removeSubrange(ix...ix)
        nRemoved += 1

    }
    return nRemoved
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! :)

Comment: Simpler: `s.remove(at: ix)`.